# fct_collapse in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a factor that's words (instances of words that difference participants said). I want to collapse it so that there are the categories "that" (every instance of the word "that") and notThat (all other words combined into one category). Naturally there are a lot of other words, and I don't want to go through and type them all. I've tried using != in various places, but it won't work. Maybe I just have the syntax wrong?

Anyway, is there a way to do this? That is, collapse all words that aren't "that" into one group?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```r
library(forcats)
x <- c("that", "something", "else")
fct_collapse(x, that = c("that"), other_level="notThat")
#> [1] that    notThat notThat
#> Levels: that notThat
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

#### Edit to show in a data frame

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(forcats)
dat <- data.frame(
  gender = factor(c(1,0,1,1,1,0), labels=c("male", "female")), 
  age = round(runif(6, 18,85)), 
  word = c("that", "something", "altogether", "different", "entirely", "that"))
dat %>% 
  mutate(word_collapse = fct_collapse(word, that="that", other_level="notThat"))
#>   gender age       word word_collapse
#> 1 female  74       that          that
#> 2   male  72  something       notThat
#> 3 female  57 altogether       notThat
#> 4 female  44  different       notThat
#> 5 female  79   entirely       notThat
#> 6   male  81       that          that
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do it based on my already existing dataset that I've loaded. So, I have dataset TRAP (which includes factors like gender, birth year, etc), and word (as mentioned above). 
So I need to make it so that in that already extant dataset it's combined, so I can do, for example, a lm comparing aspects of "that" and all things that aren't "that"

basically this type of thing: notFree_speech <- fct_collapse(TRAP$type,
                               free_speech = c("free_speech"),
                               notFree = c("citation","reading"))
but with "that" and "notThat"

Comment: @bauglir I edited the answer to show it working in a data frame.